# Connecting a bridge to CenturyLink Router actiontec c1000a

Tags: router, wireless-bridge

I don't get to do a lot of networking, but I'm starting to get into it more for family projects mostly.

This would likely apply to multiple different routers provided by CenturyLink or Qwest.

Right now I have an Actiontec c1000a acting as a modem/router that all my devices are connected to wirelessly.

I have one device on the other side of the house that needs a wired connection.

I have a buffalo Air Station Wireless-G router using DD-WRT firmware that I would like to use as a bridge, and after doing a lot of research I'm fairly certain I have everything configured there properly. In the dd-wrt interface I join to my wireless network provided by c1000a and it says it's successful, but then the node doesn't actually show up so it doesn't look like it actually joined.

My main question is, is it possible for me to use the c1000a as a gateway router that other routers can connect to, and if so, what would I need to configure on the c1000a to allow this to happen?

When I try to google this question, I never find my scenerio, just a lot of people wanting to use a different router to handle the wifi and asking how to use the c1000a as a transparent bridge.

I'm pretty sure if I used the c1000a as a transparent bridge and hooked another router(router3) up to it to handle everything that I could get my buffalo to connect to router3, but I'd prefer not to buy another router for the sole purpose of getting around my Actiontec router if I can get it to do what I want.

I can provide specific settings, but I'm not sure what's pertinent for this question so just let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to configure a static IP address (on your network but outside the c1000a's DHCP range, maybe `192.168.1.2`?) on the DD-WRT router as well as make sure the DHCP server is disabled.

Comment: Thanks @heavyd. As far as I know I have that setup already on my dd-wrt router, I'm using 192.168.0.2 on that one, and 192.168.0.1 for my main router. I've also adjusted all my security settings, made sure everything is using the same channel/security etc. as the c1000a. There is a static routing option on the c1000a interface, I'm wondering if I need to do something there to tell it about my second router but haven't had much luck

Comment: You shouldn't have to tell router A about router B.  Since they're on the same network they should be able to communicate without additional configuration.  Just to verify configuration: Your "Wireless Mode" is set to Client Bridged, correct?  Can you ping the c1000a from dd-wrt once connected?

Comment: @heavyd yes it is set to Client Bridged, but no I couldn't ping the c1000a. Here is a screencast of some of the steps I've done, trying to join the wireless network http://screencast.com/t/VYnytRgKsE. One thing that might help diagnose, it seems that part or all of the time, at least right now, I can't connect to the dd-wrt when my computer is cabled to it by putting 192.168.0.2 in the browser, unless the router is also cabled to the c1000a, which doesn't make sense to me. Thank you for helping me work through this.

Comment: Just to clarify previous comment. I'm able to connect to my router at 192.168.0.2 when connected to my wireless network if my router is connected via ethernet to my c1000a, but I'm having trouble connecting to it directly with an ethernet cable. For the most part, I setup my buffalo following this video, starting at about 1 minute http://youtu.be/KE1mr-TXUPo.

Comment: Based on your screencast, it looks like the wireless link is not up, which explains why you can't connect when the router is not hard wired, you probably can't reach router 1 to get an IP from the DHCP server.  You've double checked Wi-Fi security settings?  Maybe try temporarily disabling security?

Comment: @heavyd Thank you. That makes sense to me now and it works :) My Security type on c1000a was set to WPA - WPA2-Personal. I incorrectly assumed WPA Personal Mixed on my buffalo was right and tried that and WPA2 Personal. Following your suggestion I tried WPA Personal for the security type and now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16120/discussion-between-mrfreester-and-heavyd).